# не получается вернуть данные из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

есть код

```
const fetchData = {
  data: [],
  ft(){
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.data.push(data))
    .finally(() => {
      document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      // return this.data
      // console.log(this.data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    console.log(this.data)
  },
  mapFt(){
    console.log(this.ft())  //.map(i => console.log(i))
  }
}

export default fetchData.ft()
```

который возвращает вот это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне забрать от туда data?

Comment: нет, пишет что не может прочитать свойство data
много что пробовал, из-за этого и получился данный вопрос на stackoverflow

Comment: наверно просто this.data[0]

Comment: this.data[0] вернет undefined

Comment: .then(data => this.data = data)

Comment: вернет пустой массив

Comment: нет, массив статический, то что я фетчем забрал я пушу в дату, и всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут промисы юзать нужно, потому что сначала `fetch(...)` вызывается асинхронно, он не успевает записать данные.

Попробуй что-нибудь такое:

```
async ft() {
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.data.push(data))
            .finally(() => {
                document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                res()
                // return this.data
                // console.log(this.data)
            })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }).then(() => console.log(this.data))
},
```

Comment: иди кури мануалы

Comment: htaccess, так может тебе покурить, если такие вопросы задаешь. ещё и некорректные

Comment: возможно, где он не корректен?

Comment: htaccess, чекай

Comment: иди кури)))) вернет он то что не может найти дата(2вараза) и так же undefined

Comment: здесь беда в том что он возвращает, а не то как он возвращает,  имхо

Comment: ну, а щас чекай. ты если даже не тестишь, то лучше попей молока иди и не отвечай

Comment: `fetch(...)` сам по себе возвращает промис. Нет необходимости его оборачивать. Просто ТС не указывает откуда он вызывает свою функцию. Потому и не получает развернутых ответов.

Comment: ну вот, ты и сам научился писать годный фетч

Comment: кстати реально можно было в ресолв фетча добавить, но если включить мозги и поменять пару строк, можно юзать data где угодно

Comment: `const response = await fetch();` `const data = await response.json()`

Comment: Получился ответ из разряда вредные советы )

Comment: это почему же ?

Answer (score 0):

**short version**

```
  async ft(){
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/')
    const data = await response.json()
    .finally(()=>{
      document.getElementById("myButton").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    })
    console.log(data.data)
    return data
  }
```

то что предложил Рустам